# libssl.so.9 missing on a new FreeBSD system when using pkg

Tags: freebsd

I just installed a fresh FreeBSD but when I try to install emacs with `pkg install emacs`, I've the following error.

```
ld-elf.so.1: Shared object "libssl.so.9" not found, required by "pkg".
```

The only thing I've done is `portsnap fetch extract`

Aside `ls`, `cd` and `man`, it's the second command on this system.

Any idea?

Comment: `portsnap` is for ports, not packages. You do not need to do that. As always, refer to the most excellent [FreeBSD Handbook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/pkgng-intro.html) for information.

Comment: Which version of FreeBSD is this? I have had the same issue with 12.0-BETA2 - its related to a recent update to OpenSSL in the base system. Some parts of the system are still playing catchup.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install `openssl`:

```
pkg install openssl
```

That will provide you with `libssl.so.9` which will be located here:

```
/usr/local/lib/libssl.so.9
```

After that, you can:

```
pkg install emacs
```

If `pkg` on your system just won't execute then you can use one of the following first:

```
pkg-static bootstrap -f 

pkg-static install pkg -f
```

Comment: You have to use `pkg-static` instead.

Comment: @arrowd No, you don't. I successfully installed it with `pkg install`.

Comment: But OP isn't able to do so. You see, his `pkg` executable can't start.

Comment: @arrowd This is a fresh install. Had he upgraded then pkg may have depended on dynamic libraries. If it just won't start then what he actually needs is pkg bootstrap or `pkg-static install pkg`. He can then use `pkg` with no issues so he doesn't have to use `pkg-static` to install emacs (which is what he is trying to) and your comment isn't providing enough information as it doesn't show anything about what actually needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I got it to work was by disabling the fingerprint and signature_type in the **/etc/pkg/FreeBSD.conf**, this is a known bug as per the forum and this is the only alternative I found to the ever time consuming alternative to portsnap fetch.

```
FreeBSD: {
  url: "pkg+http://pkg.FreeBSD.org/${ABI}/latest",
  mirror_type: "srv",
  #signature_type: "fingerprints",
  #fingerprints: "/usr/share/keys/pkg",
  enabled: yes
}
```

Yes, I know it makes security a concern.